# Displaying warning if no featured image has been set - Post Editor

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, warnings, multi-author

I run a multi-author website and many of my users are forgetting to set a featured image for their post. This is a big problem as my theme depends highly on featured images to keep a consistent feel throughout the site.

I've found a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-featured-image/) that allows for a default featured image to be set if the user doesn't set one but this is far from perfect.

Is there anyway to have an error message pop-up when the featured image is not set and the user tries to publish, or potentially disabling the ability to publish a new post until a featured image is assigned?

Ideally I'd like to find a solution that pops up before the page is reloaded, to limit the frustration of the user/avoid unnecessary steps and time wasted reloading the page.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score -1):

you can hook yourself into save_post and check there if the image is present. if it is not there fire an admin_notice.

more here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15355/32776

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Edit:
I dont have the time to provide working code but here is a copy paste from the links above.
i think that you have to figure what the field name is. maybe "thums" works.

as a start go to your functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'check_if_image_set' );

function check_if_image_set( $post_id ) {

    //verify post is not a revision
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

        //http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
        if ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'thumb', true) )

    }else{
           add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
        }

}

function my_admin_notice(){
    //print the message
    echo '<div id="message">
       <p>No Picture Set!!!</p>
    </div>';
    //make sure to remove notice after its displayed so its only displayed when needed.
    remove_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
}
?>
```

Best Regards,
Simon

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simon, are you able to provide a little more clarification as to exactly how I'm able to do this?